# Remove border around objects after adjusting HSL in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom

I'd like to change the color of the sky in a picture I took in Lightroom.  I'm using the blue saturation slider in the HSL module.  However, when I adjust it a lot, the objects in the photo get a light border (it's the original color of the sky).  I was wondering if there's a way to remove that border or have the HSL module be more aggressive in how it identified "blue"?  Here's a zoomed-in photo to illustrate.

Original:
[image]

Modified:
[image]

Comment: Post the same crop pre-processing… and bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to create the effect I'm seeking using only Lightroom in the following way:

1. Create a `Graduated Filter` that encapsulates the entire image at full strength.  This can be done by clicking outside the image and dragging away or by moving the placeholder after creating it.
2. Use the `Range Mask` with type `Color`.
3. Pick the sky's color using the eyedropper.
4. Apply the required style adjustments (in this example: change `Color`, `Temp`, and `Exposure`).
5. Adjust the `Amount` slider until the white border disappears.

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Some [visible halos remaining](https://imgur.com/1VQzzxW), though.

Comment: I guess I could've been more aggressive with the amount slider.

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting a different technique (using Gimp but you have equivalent tools in your Adobe suite):

- Add a layer below, fill with the color you want for the sky (or even something even darker/saturated)
- Use Color-to-alpha to make a color transparent (of you course you pick the average color of the sky).
- Using the tools slider you can control how much opacity you leave, so you can choose a result somewhere between your original sky and the layer you added.
- If your sky is not uniform the small color variation will translate into opacity variations, so your final result will also be non uniform, which avoids the "painted-over" look.

[image]

Comment: That is an interesting approach.